# Calendar change URL on select with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery UI picker and I am wondering if it's possible when someone pick a date, it automatically redirect them to the URL like so:

`index.php?date=2013-10-15`

Here's the plug-in I am using.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

`Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />`

Comment: Well, I thought jQuery's UI is pretty common and everyone know what it is. :\

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1)  What you need is [**`window.location.href`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077808/1671639), which is the used to redirect the page.  You can customize way the window to opened.

2) Once you select the date in datepicker (`onSelect`), you can combine the `change` event as @T.J. Crowder said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471992/1671639).

You can try like this

```
$("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $(this).change();
      }
    })
    .change(function() {
      window.location.href = "index.php?date=" + this.value;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function () {
            window.open(document.URL + '?date=' + this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvL84/1/)

Comment: Very nice! But I opted for `window.location.href` since I am redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work out as per your requirement.

Date:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

});

function myFunc(){
    var dateData = $("#datepicker").val();

    if(dateData != '' ){

        var url = "http://www.index.php?date="+ dateData ;
        window.open(url);

    }
}


</script>

<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="myFunc();" /></p>
</body>
```